# Zend Framework: Does adding a class to Zend_Amf instantiate it?

Tags: zend-framework, amf

I'm wondering if I can use a constructor within a class I am writing to provide a Zend_Amf gateway. When I do:

```
$server = new Zend_Amf_Server();
$server->setClass('Foo');
$response = $server->handle();
echo $response;
```

Does foo's constructor get run here? The reason for asking is that I need my 'Foo' class to access other objects and it would make sense to initialise them in my constructor. If not, whats the best way to approach this?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is No but you can pass an instantiated object in i.e setClass($foo)